# Change Response Class property's naming in Swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, swagger-ui

I'm using Swagger and using the display of Response Class. 
my Controller class looks like this

```
    [SwaggerResponse((int)HttpStatusCode.OK, typeof(ICollection<FileVerdict>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetUnsafeFiles(Guid scanId)
    {
            ICollection<FileVerdict> response = await _managementOperations.GetUnsafeFiles(scanId);
            return Ok(response);                       
        }
    }
```

FileVerdict Class looks like:

```
public class FileVerdict
{
       public string SHA256 { get; set; }
}
```

So the property in the Response Class should be written all with UpperCase ("SHA256"), but instead it looked like "shA256" .

Swagger Display:

[image: Swagger Display]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try marking the FileVerdict class with the attributes shown below:

```
[DataContract]
public class FileVerdict 
{
    [DataMember(Name = "SHA256")]
    public string SHA256 { get;set; }
}
```